# additive order of any zero divisor in $Z_{p^2}$ is p, is it true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields, abelian-groups

This result was used in a proof of a theorem, i am not sure if it's true. can someone tell the proof idea.

Can it be generalized to additive order of any zero divisor in $Z_{p^k}$, is there any formula to calculate the additive order of zero divisors of $Z_{p^k}$ in general ?

Comment: Why don't you try generalizing it? What are the zero divisors of $\Bbb Z_8$? What are their additive orders? How about $\Bbb Z_{27}$ or $\Bbb Z_{16}$?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667019/prove-that-the-divisors-of-zero-in-the-ring-mathbb-z-n-are-precisely-those-el) and apply it for $n=p^k$.

Comment: zero divisors of $Z_8$ are 2,4,6. O(2) =4, O(4)=2, O(6) =4

Comment: @RisingStar And if you look at the prime factorisations of the zero divisors $2, 4$ and $6$, do you see a connection between that and their respective additive orders? If you don't see it right away, then looking at the other two rings I suggested is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the zero divisors of ${\Bbb Z}_{p^k}$ are exactly the nonzero elements $a$ with $\gcd(a,p^k)\ne 1$, i.e., the zero divisors are exactly the nonzero multiples of $p$. Then the $p^{k-1}$-multiple of a zero divisor $a$ written as $a=pb$ is $p^{k-1}\cdot a = p^{k-1}pb = p^kb=0$.

Comment: So the additive orders of zero divisors could be any thing between, $p, p^2 , ...... , p^{k-1}$

Comment: More generally see the [Order Test.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1188614/242)