# Let $R=\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_3\oplus \mathbb Z_5$. How many zero divisors are there in $R$?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $R=\mathbb Z_2\oplus \mathbb Z_3\oplus \mathbb Z_5$.Then Total
> number of the zero divisors in $R?$
>
> (A) $15$
>
> (B) $10$
>
> (C) $20$
>
> (D) $22$

**Solution** We know that

- $x$ is a unit $\Longleftrightarrow \
  gcd(\vert x\vert ,30)=1$
- $x$ is a Zero Divisor $\Longleftrightarrow \
  gcd(\vert x\vert,30)\neq 1$

Since $R$ has $2.3.5=30$ elements.So number of elements in $R$ whose order is relatively prime to **30** is  $\phi(30)=8\implies$ number of elements in $R$ whose order is not relatively prime to **30** are $30-\phi(30)=30-8=22\implies $ $R$ has **22** zero divisors.

But the answer key says the solution is 20

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You are right, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667019/prove-that-the-divisors-of-zero-in-the-ring-mathbb-z-n-are-precisely-those-el). Please say why $20$ should be correct.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:Why 20 should be correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You made a claim "But the correct answer is 20" without proof. Do you have a scan?

Comment: (The point is, whoever told you that 20 is correct has made an error.)

Comment: @DietrichBurde:Actually, I'm solving the text exercises...in the answer key it is given that option (C) is correct...thats why i'm asking

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. Can you show us the answer key? It is possible to confuse the exercise number, sometimes.

Comment: Answer keys frequently contain errors.

Comment: @JBL:yeah,it may be the  case also...

Comment: And often one confuses the exercise number. So there is no way of telling what is true for us, except that your answer is correct.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:I got it...I cross checked the answer key...key is wrong

Comment: Using the totient function requires showing that $R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$, which, of course, is true by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

As we've already settled in the comments, your figure of $22$ is the correct one.

The totient function is a great way to do it, but let's give another way just to crosscheck:

Since $R$ is finite, [each element is a unit or a zero divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60969/every-nonzero-element-in-a-finite-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-zero-divisor) (I count $0$ among the zero divisors.) So it suffices to count the units. To be a unit, it has to be a unit on every coordinate. There's only one unit in $F_2$, two in $F_3$ and four in $F_5$, so there ought to be $8$ units. The whole ring has $30$, and $30$ less $8$ is $22$, again.

Comment: And even if you don't count 0 as a zero divisor, that would make the answer 21, and still 20 would not be the correct answer.